# How can I make css sprite in this situation?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have a site where I am showing 8/9 images in a row. In the build phase it is ok to make 9 http call in my local pc but I want to go for css-sprite technique to reduce no of http calls in the actual website. But I am unable to produce such css-sprite. Please help.

The html+css code is simple:

```
    <style>
      a img{ width: 32px; height: 32px; }
    </style>

<a href="http://www.twitter.com/godhulii">
      <img alt="@godhulii" 
src="twitter.jpg" title="follow me @godhulii"> </a>

      <a href="http://somewhereinblog.net/blog/seoul">
            <img alt="somewhereinblog.net/blog/seoul" 
src="somewhereinblog.jpg" title="somewhereinblog.net/blog/seoul"> </a>

      <a href="http://www.youtube.com/seoulbuet" >
            <img alt="bookmark this site" 
src="youtube.gif" title="youtube.com/user/seoulbuet"> </a>
```

---

For your convenience (or expecting you will create a css-sprite), I have setup this code in jsbin testing environment: http://jsbin.com/ugabez/edit#source

Thanks for the reply,
-seoul.

Comment: There is not enough information to go on here.  What are the sprites for? Where do you want them displayed?

Comment: If you go to the jsbin link and render, you will see the output. I just want the same output, but with a single http call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpritMe can help you create sprites for your website.

You can find more information [HERE](http://spriteme.org/)